# Windows PATHEXT with *.lnk files and Cygwin Make

Tags: windows, make

I don't want my `%PATH%` environment variable to be polluted with a bunch of directories and I want to have more control over what executables can be found. I created a folder `C:\bin`, added it to `%PATH%` and also added `*.lnk` to `%PATHEXT%`. `C:\bin` looks like this

[image: file list here]

Starting those programs from the command-line is not a problem at all. But I have a problem with the Gnu Make tool (from Cygwin). It can not find the programs from this folder.

```
C:\Users\niklas>make -f Desktop\test.mak
make: python: Command not found
test.mak:37: recipe for target 'dirs' failed
make: *** [dirs] Error 127
```

I wonder why make can not find these programs? Doesn't it use the Windows way to create a subprocess? Using Python, for instance, it works!

```
import os
os.system("sublime-text")
# Sublime Text 3 opens ...
```

How can I fix this problem? If possible, without putting the actual directories of the executables into the PATH variable.